# selecting rows from sub-inquiries, SQL, solving

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I can't seem to do this no matter what I try: So basically I have this example of tables:

```
 table: HOTEL
 HID    NAME
 ----------------------- 
 H1     HILTON     
 H2     MOUNTAIN INN
 H3     TROPICANA


 table: Renting
 ID     JMBG   HID 
 -----------------------
 1      J2     H1
 2      J2     H2
 3      J2     H3
 4      J1     H1


 table: Clijents
 JMBG    NAME
 -----------------------
 J1      ALICE
 J2      JOHN
```

From here , I am supposed to find all the hotels that have rented to all the klients, or in this case just **H1** 
This was my best try, i didnt work ;(

```
    SELECT HID FROM HOTEL H
WHERE H.HID IN
     (select HID, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS RENTED
        FROM RENTINGS R
        GROUP BY R.HID )
   AND R.RENTED=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIJENTS )
```

Comment: Hi jerry check my answer for your previous question.

Comment: BTW Your query sample seem wrong, first your table `R` doesnt have `RENTED` field and you put the `AND R.Rented` outside subquery at that level only `H` is visible. Check your query formated using http://poorsql.com and will see what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need `count(distinct)` in case one hotel rent to same client multiple times.

.

```
SELECT HID
FROM Renting 
GROUP BY HID
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT JMBG) =  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIJENTS )
```